# Iterate from index n in Handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js, template-engine

Is there a way to iterate over an array in Handlebars, starting from a point other than zero and ending at a point before the last item in the array?

In other words, the Handlebars equivalent of:

```
var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];

for(var i=2; i<5; i++){
    // Do Stuff
}
```

I could parse the data with js before it gets passed to Handlebars, or build a helper, but I'm curious as to whether there is this functionality built in.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in ability to do that. You can only use `@last` and `@first` inside [#each](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#iteration). But the better approach would be to filter the data before passing it to template. Or use a helper if excess items realy need to be used somewhere else, but it's very rare case, I think so.